# google account on android permanently asking for sign-in after change from googlemail to gmail

Tags: gmail

I have recently changed my email from ...@googlemail.com to ...@gmail.com (can be done in settings). 
Now android continuously tells me it can't sign-in with my ...@googlemail.com account.
All other google services changed automatically the email name, leaving everything else unchanged.

Every other interaction with gmail works flawlessly (web login, thunderbird, ...). Only Android seems to have these issues...

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected issue for this change.

To fix this you only need to delete the google account in your android device and then add it again with the updated email.
Finally a reboot is needed to stop the notifications.

You don't risk any data loss by doing this.

Source: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/vxxPMMv5kXg